# Create a new session as a copy of another on Livy

Tags: rest, session, apache-spark, bigdata

I use livy to use Spark as a service. My application send some commands to livy as code, however, spark needs to initialize some variables(read some files, make some map&reduce operations etc.) and this take time. This initializing part is common for all sessions. After the construction, different statements may be sent to these sessions.

What i wonder is when livy creates a session, is it possible to copy an old session line an image or should it start everything from scratch?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some amount of researches, it is not possible with Livy server. The only responsibility of Livy is serving a rest service for applications to reach the Spark framework in the Hadoop cluster. For each request (whether batch or session), it opens a seperate spark-shell. Therefore, it is not possible to clone an existing session.

Also one more addition, I really didn't like the way livy server handles the external dependencies. Generating a fat jar is not an appropriate way for hadoop environment, since there are a lot of them. However, if you implement a spark application with command-line arguments it is an easy way to communicate with the Hadoop environment via HTTP with an interactive manner.